# loop and list values

Tags: jquery

I have an array. What is simple way to loop array and display value in paragraph putting one in each line

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an array and want to separate the values with a `<br>`, you can simply [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the values:

```
var arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
    elem = /* refers to the paragraph */;
elem.innerHTML = arr.join("<br>");
```

And with DOM methods only:

```
var i = 0,
    n = arr.length;
if (n) {
    elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i++]));
    while (i < n) {
        elem.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i++]));
    }
}
```

Comment: p already exists. When i print like this $("#pop").innerHTML = arr.join("<br>"); nothing happen?

Comment: $('#pop') is a jQueryized object. You can do $('#pop').text( arr.join('<br>') ) or $('#pop').get(0).innerHTML = arr.join('<br>')

Comment: thank you when i do $('#pop').text( arr.join('</br>') ) it printing </br> also..i want to render into break not print it

Comment: Use the `html` method instead: `$('#pop').html(arr.join('<br>'))`.

Comment: this is very very very good.Can i also clearify content of pop before adding new val? $('#pop').text('')?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var a = ['john', 'went', 'to'], p = $('<p>')
$(a).each(function() {
    $(p).text( $(p).text() + ' ' + this );
});

$.trim(  $(p).text() )

$(p).appendTo('body')

// You want "\n" for a newline and "<br/>" for a line break element.
```

Pure DOM:

```
document.body.appendChild( (document.createElement('p')).appendChild( document.createTextNode(['john ', 'went'].join('<br>') )) )
```